# How to merge React Data Grid with react-infinite-scroll-component?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, vertical-scrolling, react-data-grid, react-infinite

I want to use React Data Grid with the react-infinite-scroll-component, is there any possibility to use it together.

The reason I want to use together to utilize the advantage of data grid features.

I tried to use "infinite scroll with scrollableTarget (a parent element which is scroll-able)" but ReactDataGrid will be as child not as parent. Any Solutions ?

If this is not possible then can I use same sort of featured data grid if available inside the infinite component.

Thanks,